# What path for the heli pilot is best?

Tags: bloons-td-6

I've been intrested in the heli pilot tower lately and it's tier 5 upgrade the Apache Prime, Special Poperations, and the Commache Commander. I can't decide which path is best. Does anyone have an idea?